# cannot create module: instance allocation for this module requires 74376 bytes which exceeds the configured maximum of 65536 bytes

Tags: runtime, benchmarking, wasm, substrate-node

Try in to benchmark node pallets after Polkadot upgrade from 0.9.36 to 0.9.38 and get `cannot create module: instance allocation for this module requires 74376 bytes which exceeds the configured maximum of 65536 bytes; breakdown of allocation requirement` error.

I double checked that node and wasm runtimes are built with `runtime-benchmarks` feature.

```
nix:devenv-shell) (devenv) bash-5.2$ COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 RUST_BACKTRACE=full nix run .#composable-bench-node --impure -- benchmark pallet --chain=picasso-dev --pallet="*" --extrinsic="*"
warning: Git tree '/home/dz/github.com/ComposableFi/composable' is dirty
warning: Using saved setting for 'extra-substituters = https://cache.nixos.org https://nix-community.cachix.org https://nixpkgs-update.cachix.org https://devenv.cachix.org https://composable-community.cachix.org' from ~/.local/share/nix/trusted-settings.json.
warning: Using saved setting for 'extra-trusted-public-keys = composable-community.cachix.org-1:GG4xJNpXJ+J97I8EyJ4qI5tRTAJ4i7h+NK2Z32I8sK8= devenv.cachix.org-1:w1cLUi8dv3hnoSPGAuibQv+f9TZLr6cv/Hm9XgU50cw= nix-community.cachix.org-1:mB9FSh9qf2dCimDSUo8Zy7bkq5CX+/rkCWyvRCYg3Fs= nixpkgs-update.cachix.org-1:6y6Z2JdoL3APdu6/+Iy8eZX2ajf09e4EE9SnxSML1W8= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=' from ~/.local/share/nix/trusted-settings.json.
2023-04-13 03:16:39 assembling new collators for new session 0 at #0    
2023-04-13 03:16:39 assembling new collators for new session 1 at #0    
Error: 
   0: Invalid input: Did not find the benchmarking metadata. This could mean that you either did not build the node correctly with the `--features runtime-benchmarks` flag, or the chain spec that you are using was not created by a node that was compiled with the flag: cannot create module: instance allocation for this module requires 74376 bytes which exceeds the configured maximum of 65536 bytes; breakdown of allocation requirement:

       * 98.06% - 72936 bytes - module functions
   0: 

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
   1: color_eyre::config::EyreHook::into_eyre_hook::{{closure}}::h075a91586537bb83
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   2: eyre::capture_handler::hc455214d4a0ef82b
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   3: eyre::error::<impl core::convert::From<E> for eyre::Report>::from::h9144b87cb2ba7d68
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   4: composable::main::h9794ada59db822a4
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   5: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h97c0b3729103fb66
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   6: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h5fc4f928913452c2
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   7: std::rt::lang_start_internal::h33bb8f2385eabf94
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   8: main<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   9: __libc_start_call_main<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  10: __libc_start_main_alias_1<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  11: _start<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>

Run with COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 environment variable to disable frame filtering.
2023-04-13 03:16:40 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot create module: instance allocation for this module requires 74376 bytes which exceeds the configured maximum of 65536 bytes; breakdown of allocation requirement:\n\n * 98.06% - 72936 bytes - module functions\n")
```

Error from https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/07c77323010d54410143103c2617ebc12e0a12f3/client/executor/src/wasm_runtime.rs#L271

It seems related to WASM page size https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aparitytech+65536&type=code . So I do not handle page size anywhere directly.

Setting `--heap-pages` to various values did not helped.

I got this run,

```bash
COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 RUST_BACKTRACE=full nix run .#composable-bench-node --impure -- benchmark pallet --chain=picasso-dev --pallet="*" --extrinsic="*" --execution=wasm  --no-verify --wasm-execution interpreted-i-know-what-i-do
```

but sure I do not want benchmark interpreter.

UPDATE:
adding PR which fails our CI https://github.com/ComposableFi/composable/pull/3469

https://github.com/ComposableFi/composable/actions/runs/4766804685/jobs/8474290562?pr=3469

UPDATE2:

Install  https://zero-to-nix.com/ (it is easy unisntall)

Run

```
COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 RUST_BACKTRACE=full nix run .#composable-bench-node --impure -- benchmark pallet --chain=picasso-dev --pallet="*" --extrinsic="*" --execution=wasm  --no-verify --wasm-execution compiled
```

to see issue

Comment: Could you please provide the exact commit on which this occurred and benchmark command that you ran? And basically everything that helps with re-producing this.

Comment: i have applied suggested patch from moonbeam about heap pages, was not enough to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to include the pr created by one of your colleagues: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13298

Comment: yeah, trying. new commits where added to parithtehc polkadot 0.9.38, so have to patch and align attempts to sync cumulus/polkadot/substrate to work on our fork. in progress testing

Comment: it worked, but afaik fix was done for Cosmwasm runtime :) Not Parachain.